# SQL Query optimization - exec time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

I am having the following query which took me 2 seconds to execute and now it takes ~10 minutes because I added 100 more entries in tables custom_redemptions and around 10 more in each other table.

With `DISTINCT` it returns me

```
Showing rows 0 - 29 (96 total, Query took 0.00156 sec)
```

I took out `DISTINCT` to track the bug and it returned me

```
 Showing rows 0 - 29 (94174080 total, Query took 0.1510 sec)
```

Is there any way to optimize this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
FROM `users_roles` a,
     `field_data_field_ypefthinos` b,
     `custom_redemptions` c,
     `field_data_field_chain_manager` e,
     `field_data_field_node_tax_inception` f,
     `field_data_field_brand_manager` j,
     `field_data_field_brand_node_ref` k,
     `field_data_field_product_ref` i,
     `field_data_field_company_manager` z,
     `field_data_field_brand_company` t
WHERE (a.rid = 4
       AND a.uid = 351
       AND b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid
       AND b.entity_id = c.branchid)
   OR
      (a.rid = 5
       AND a.uid = 351
       AND e.field_chain_manager_uid = a.uid
       AND e.entity_id = f.entity_id
       AND f.field_node_tax_inception_tid = c.chainid)
   OR
      (a.rid = 9
       AND a.uid = 351
       AND j.field_brand_manager_uid = a.uid
       AND j.entity_id = k.field_brand_node_ref_nid
       AND k.entity_id = i.field_product_ref_nid
       AND i.entity_id = c.couponid)
   OR
      (a.rid = 6
       AND a.uid = 351
       AND z.field_company_manager_uid = a.uid
       AND z.entity_id = t.field_brand_company_nid
       AND t.entity_id = k.field_brand_node_ref_nid
       AND k.entity_id = i.field_product_ref_nid
       AND i.entity_id = c.couponid)
```

Comment: Are you aware you do **CARTESIAN PRODUCT** with massive `WHERE`? It basically means that your intermediate result will have size SIZE(users_roles) x SIZE(field_data_field_ypefthinos) x...x SIZE(field_data_field_brand_company).

Comment: Try to use JOIN instead to combine e.g. ``a.uid`` and ``z.field_company_manager_uid``

Comment: You should break your request rather than make a huge

Comment: I don;t see that as the issue @Zl3n. Getting 94 iterations of 1M rows ?

Comment: Use JOIN instructions, it will optimize you execution time , see documentation : 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Different products, may perform better/worse in some cases.

Comment: @jarlh looks like mysql to me, can't edit tags until the edit is rejected though

Comment: So will INNER JOIN do the job?

Comment: Inner join what? You're already doing different (implicit) inner joins depending on the a.rid value. Unfortunately you're also doing cross joins - with lots of data.

Comment: Several of the tables are never referenced, neither in select list or in where clause. Why are they in from list?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. You have the `OR` of 4 conditions.  Turn the query into the `UNION` of 4 `SELECTs`, each with one of the `OR` conditions.

Step 2. Remove the unused tables in each `SELECT` (to get rid of the Cartesian products).

Step 3. Add `INDEX(uid, rid)` (in either order) to `a`.