# SQL Query optimization convert

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

I tried to optimize (convert) this SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
                FROM `users_roles` a, `field_data_field_ypefthinos` b, `custom_redemptions` c, `field_data_field_chain_manager` e, `field_data_field_node_tax_inception` f, `field_data_field_brand_manager` j, `field_data_field_brand_node_ref` k, `field_data_field_product_ref` i, `field_data_field_company_manager` z, `field_data_field_brand_company` t
                WHERE
                (a.rid = 4
                AND a.uid = ?
                AND b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid
                AND b.entity_id = c.branchid)
```

to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
    FROM `custom_redemptions` AS c
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_ypefthinos` as b
    ON b.entity_id = c.branchid
INNER JOIN `users_roles` as A
    ON b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid
    WHERE a.rid 4 AND a.uid 351
```

But it's giving me syntax error

For the original question take a look at [SQL Query optimization - exec time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496344/sql-query-optimization-exec-time/32496720#32496720)

Comment: `WHERE a.rid = 4 AND a.uid = 351`

Comment: What does `field_data_field_node_tax_inception` f have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot you `=` sign in `WHERE` clause :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
        FROM `custom_redemptions` AS c
    INNER JOIN `field_data_field_ypefthinos` as b
        ON b.entity_id = c.branchid
    INNER JOIN `users_roles` as A
        ON b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid
        WHERE a.rid = 4 AND a.uid = 351
```

Hope this helps.